# Insert new document in nested documents in MongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am a beginner in MongoDB. Please see my models below.

```
public class Technology
{
    public Technology()
    {
        ProductGroups = new List<ProductGroup>();
    }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductGroup> ProductGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ProductGroup
{

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Now the data shows like below.

[image]

I am try to add the `ProductGroup` ( it's a BsonDocument Collection) collection in `Technology`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Model of Technology as

```
[BsonElementAttribute("productgroups")]
public IList<ProductGroup> ProductGroups{ get; set; }
```

Then,

```
var productGroup = new BsonDocument().Add("_id", productGroup_id).Add("Name", name);

var technologies = database.GetCollection("technology");
var technology = technologies.FindOneById(ObjectId.Parse(technology_id));

technology["productgroups"] = new BsonArray().Add(BsonValue.Create(productGroup));

technologies.Save(technology);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I try to do this method. But '.FindOneById' is not getting visual studio intellisence. I am using v2.0.1.27

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath If you have MongoDB.Driver.dll  referenced, then check http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/bdd981a2-4af3-e84c-a03c-021c371bb1ce.htm. If this doesn't work you can check any other option using VS intellisense.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use generic types where you can. Because this code `parent["ProductGroups"]` is dangerous place for any refactoring.
2. Your task can be done in one query

`var productGroup = new ProductGroup { Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), Name = model.Name };`
`var collection = database.GetCollection<Technology>("Technology");`
`var update = Builders<Technology>.Update.AddToSet(x => x.ProductGroups, productGroup);`
`await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(x => x.Id == model._id, update);`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. But i can't get this (FindOneAndUpdateAsync) method in C# intellisence

Comment: How do you get collection?

Answer (score 1):

@CodingDefined I change my code as per the v2.0.1.27

Please see my code below. Thank you very much for your help.

```
var productGroup = new BsonDocument()
                      .Add("_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId())
                      .Add("Name", model.Name);

BsonDocument parent = null;

var _parent = Collection.FindOneByIdAs(typeof(BsonDocument), model._id);

if (_parent != null)
{

   parent = _parent.ToBsonDocument();

   parent["ProductGroups"] = new BsonArray().Add(BsonValue.Create(productGroup));

   Collection.Save(parent);

}
```

Please make sure, the new child record is not clearing the existing records

```
parent["ProductGroups"] = parent["ProductGroups"].AsBsonArray.Add(productGroup);
```